# IOTA Chrysalis Client library Rust example error

Tags: documentation, chrysalis

When I try cargo build the Rust example posted on the IOTA Chrysalis documentation website [Getting Started with Rust](https://client-lib.docs.iota.org/libraries/rust/getting_started.html)

```
use iota::Client;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let iota = Client::builder() // Crate a client instance builder
        .with_node("https://api.lb-0.testnet.chrysalis2.com")
        .unwrap()
        .finish()
        .await
        .unwrap();

    let info = iota.get_info().await.unwrap();
    println!("Nodeinfo: {:?}", info);
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

[image]

I also added

```
[dependencies]
iota-core = { git = "https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.rs", branch = "dev" }
```

to `Cargo.toml`

Also when the example is run directly on the website the following errors occur:

[image]

Can someone please help me to solve the errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this example you also have to add `tokio = { version = "1.1", features = ["full"] }` to your Cargo.toml like here https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.rs/blob/dev/examples/Cargo.toml

For the website it's only to be viewed there and you can't run it because play.rust-lang.org doesn't have support for the required dependencies

Comment: Thanks, it worked